# Check the scrollTop() of document after few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, delay, scrolltop

I want to check `$(document).scrollTop()` two seconds after the page loads. How can I do that? Can somebody help me? I am newbie in jQuery?

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$(document).delay(2000).scrollTop()
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is your fiend.

Comment: use `setTimeout` rather than delay

Comment: Remember that [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) can only be used for queued effects in jQuery. It is not intended as a replacement for `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using the [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) function after the `document.ready` was triggered:

```
$(function(){ //wait for document ready

  setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).scrollTop() 
  }, 2000) //execute your function after 2 seconds.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to fire an event handler when the document is loaded. That event is the document ready event.

The second step is to create a timeout that will execute the required function after a specified delay.

```
var scrollTimeout = null;
var jDocument = $(document);
jDocument.ready(function () { //An event fired when the document finishes loading.
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function () { //A function the will be executed after 2000ms
        jDocument.scrollTop(); //your code goes here.
    }, 2000);
});
```